# SQL. Repair counter row by update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Maybe it's a duplicate or / and probably solution is very easy, but I couldn't find any answer or better to say to write the proper search query down.

Assume I have the following table

```
 ----------------------
| parent | child | pos |
 ----------------------
|   0    |    1  |  0  |
|   0    |    5  |  1  |
|   0    |    3  |  5  |
|   1    |    8  |  0  |
|   1    |    9  |  0  |
|   1    |    7  |  0  |
|   2    |    8  |  3  |
|   2    |    9  |  4  |
 ----------------------
```

As you see the pos rows are kind of broken. For example, for parent 0 and its childres the pos values are 0, 1, 5 instead of 0, 1, 2. For parent 1 and its children they are 0, 0, 0 also instead of 0, 1, 2

There is absolutely no logic behind child and pos. I just randomized them to show that pos doesn't depend on the child, but the order of children is defined by its pos value. And if there was an order before, it should be the same.

And now the question: is it possible to "repair" this pos-row using an update sql statement, i.e. that the pos's would be unbroken and complete and always start by 0?

I'm looking for one solution or more solutions for oracle, mysql and ms sql server. It's because we are working with all them three.

And this is how the wished result should look like

```
 ----------------------
| parent | child | pos |
 ----------------------
|   0    |    1  |  0  |
|   0    |    5  |  1  |
|   0    |    3  |  2  |
|   1    |    8  |  0  |
|   1    |    9  |  1  |
|   1    |    7  |  2  |
|   2    |    8  |  0  |
|   2    |    9  |  1  |
 ----------------------
```

Thank you in advance.

Ps.
The solution of A.D. for mysql is working for me

Comment: Which database do you want an answer for? Why no love for DB2 or Sybase or SQLite or Postgres or mSQL? It's much better if you pick just one.

Comment: Please tag your question with the correct database you are using.  Why would you need to solve this problem in three very different databases?

Comment: Its better to narrow the question to single database and add a sqlfiddle for the database and what you have tried so far.

Comment: With respect, it's not obvious -- to me -- how your "pos rows are kind of broken." Can you please be more specific about how they are supposed to be filled in?

Comment: what's the logic behind `pos` values and `child` values, we understand the logic of relation between `parent and pos` but what about `child`? `I mean which child should be 0, 1 or 2!?` or it does not matter!?

Comment: I need for all three databases, because we have all them three. And there is absolutely no logic behind child and pos. I just randomized them to show that pos doesn't depend on the child id

Comment: @OllieJones I meant, the order is 'broken'. For example, for parent 0 and its childres the pos values are 0, 1, 5 instead of 0,1,2. For parent 1 and its children they are 0, 0, 0 also instead of 0, 1, 2

Comment: @FarhangAmary'Ferhęg' it does matter, the order of children is defined by its pos value. Actualy I just want to reorder pos values so that they start with 0, there are no wholes, ie. 0, 1, 2 and not 0, 1, 5 and for every new parent they begin by 0 again

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the MS SQL

```
update source_table
set source_table.POS = newposition_table.new_pos
from my_table source_table
inner join (select parent, 
                   child, 
                   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by parent order by parent, pos) - 1 new_pos
            from my_table) newposition_table
on source_table.child = newposition_table.child
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this solution for mysql

```
UPDATE your_table
, (
    SELECT parent
    , child
    , @num := IF(@parent = parent, @num + 1, 0) AS rownum
    , @parent := parent
    FROM your_table
    , (SELECT @parent := '', @num := -1) AS dummy
) AS your_table2
SET your_table.pos = your_table2.rownum
WHERE your_table.parent = your_table2.parent
AND your_table.child = your_table2.child
```

I assumed that the logic of the **pos** value is the natural order of the database.

So basically, this query create a new rownum value for every breaking point.

```
SELECT parent
, child
, @num := IF(@parent = parent, @num + 1, 0) AS rownum
, @parent := parent
FROM your_table
, (SELECT @parent := '', @num := -1) AS dummy
```

And then the values are used to update the table

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's working fine for mysql. I don't why you got some negative votes :(